# How NOT persist object inside entity with Doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have the following class that is persisted using Doctrine, but I don't want that the `knowledgeArea` and `knowledgeLevel` attributes be inserted because they are objects, not attributes.

What I need to do to not insert these objects, but only the attributes with the reference to they?

**NOTE**: I'm learnig Doctrine, I think that I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure. And I'm using MySQL.

```
class Knowledge {

    /** @Id @Column(name="id", type="bigint") @generatedValue(strategy="AUTO") **/    
    private $id;

    /** @Column(name="name", type="string") **/
    private $name;

    /** @Column(name="description", type="text") **/
    private $description;

    /** @Column(name="exibition_order", type="integer") **/
    private $exibitionOrder;

    /**         
    * @ManyToOne (targetEntity="KnowledgeArea", inversedBy="knowledges")
    * @JoinColumn(name="knowledge_area_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    **/
    private $knowledgeArea; #this is an object

    /** 
    * @ManyToOne (targetEntity="KnowledgeLevel", inversedBy="knowledges")
    * @JoinColumn(name="knowledge_level_id", referencedColumnName="id")    
    **/
    private $knowledgeLevel; #this is an object
```

Comment: What database are you using here?

Comment: Ok, so based on your relationships, data is saved appropriately.  MySQL has no way to save objects anyways, all it can do is save data in the tables that own the keys for those relationships.  There is nothing special you need to do.

Comment: @gview But is not saving. When I try to persist the knowledge object, Doctrine try to insert a new KnowledgeLevel and a new KnowledgeArea too, but this isn't right. I want only the reference of these objects in the Knowledge object, but this is not occuring. Or Doctrine insert all new objects or an error occurs. I want to insert only the attributes that aren't objects, and from the objects, get the reference (foreign key), but not insert a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that the question you have is how to set the foreign key relationships?  The typical way is to use references.  Inside a Symfony2 controller as an example you would have:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$knowledge = new Knowledge();
$knowledge->setKnowledgearea($em->getReference('AcmeBundle:Knowledges', 3));
```

If you're using some other framework, you need the doctrine entitymanager object, but the idea is the same.

This is [documented here.](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#reference-proxies)